# WPF login and REMEMBER_ME. Where to save details

Tags: wpf, api, authentication

So I have created a WPF with a local DB, however for billing I get the users to log into the WPF application which uses an API I made to check their subscription status.

Everything is working smoothly however I have been requested if there can be a 'remember me' autologin feature as the app runs in their business daily and they don't want to log in every morning.

I want to do this but I'm a bit lost as to the correct procedure or pathway or what is the right direction.
as a note: there isn't any sensitive data etc so leaving it easy to access isn't really the end of the world.

Options that I can think of:
User logs in and has "remember me" ticked:
1.

- login is verified and API key is saved into registry
- Next boot, if there is a value in registry for API, check this works to access data.  If not, re run login.
- IF apikey were found in registry.. there isn't much that it can be used for unless the person knows all my API endpoints etc.. which are all PUT, no delete or even get..

2. Store actual username and perhaps a bcrypt of the password in registry

- I don't like this method as it means the user and pass are out in the open and can be used in the program directly, whereas the API can't be used in the program, just externally if someone wanted to go to the effort of coding it all!

Anyway, thats all I can think of to bypass a login screen.
I'm sure there is a better way and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with option 1. That way you're never storing the user creds, and you can revoke access server side if necessary by invalidating the cached API key.

Check out the [DPAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-use-data-protection) for storing secrets locally. It lets you encrypt data based on the current Windows user, so other users won't be able to decrypt even if they can access the data in eg registry.

Comment: great thanks Gaz, ill take a look